# Magento - How do I merge an updated products database with a live customer database?

Tags: magento

Currently I have a live Magento 1.4.x site and a 1.6.x development site. I have put some new products into the 1.6 site and a couple of test transactions.

I would like to be able to import the existing 1.4 customer data to the 1.6 site (instead of recreating my products on the existing 1.4, which is doable but not what I want to do.)

My plan is to delete the sales_, customer_ and newsletter_ tables from the 'dev', then copy the live 1.4 to some other database, quickly upgrade that to 1.6, mysqldump sales_, customer_ and newsletter_, import the data into 'dev' and then set 'dev' to live.

I can test this procedure, see how long it takes and then do it at night, hopefully not needing to be in maintenance mode for too long. However, has anyone else done this task already and am I missing out on any really, really important tables to copy across or anything else of concern?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you want to test anything on a dev sight, do it programatically so you can run the same script on your live server when you like the script. Or do easy to repeat actions.
Playing with the database like that is extremely fragile and error prone.

Answer (score 0):

Magento can be a bit precious about it's database so i would avoid touching it directly.

If you login to the Magento admin and go to: System => Import / Export => Profiles
You will see there are already export profiles for both products and customers. Simply run the export on your dev store and then import on your live shop.

Although you may want to take a database backup before running the import.

If you're going to import the products.
Copy the images into your media folder before running the import. That way the images will also get migrated.

Comment: Will I get customer transactions if I import/export on profiles?